# Converting Numeric Date Value into Date Time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, time, substring

I have a query which joins several tables.  Among these tables there is a column name which is called EffectiveDate and displays date as a numeric value (e.g. 20030718.195700000).  Is it possible for this to be shown in the query as one column named of Effective Date in a format like this: 2003-07-18 7:57:00 PM (remove the last 3 microseconds)?  I'm not sure how the conversion would look like and how it would fit in my existing query.

Query:

```
   select SerialNum as [Serial Number],ts_sitename As Site,(case m.Scratched
   when 0 then 'Live'
   when 1 then 'Free'
   END) as Status,  Note as Comment
   from ((Media m join TheSites_tab s on m.SiteId = s.ts_sitenum) join MediaGenT g on         m.MediaId = g.mg_medianum) join Note n on m.NoteId = n.NoteId 
   where Destroyed = '0';
```

If anyone can post a solution I am going to test it right away.  Please note I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
substring(cast([date] as varchar(18)), 10,2)
```